# Store method values and validate if the value is true

Tags: java, variables, methods

Let say that I have 2 projects in Netbeans; 'Pro1' & 'Pro2'.

I need to call a method in `Pro2` which is `public int method1` into `Pro1`. Since I call the `method1` in `Pro1`, I need to store the values of `method1` in a variable which is `storeMethod1` and so I need to check if the values stored is correct or not.

So how can I do this? Is the code example for `Pro1` is correct?

EDIT: Project already add in the libraries. Everything is okay except the if statement

Pro2 code example:

```
public int method1(String a, String b, boolean c, String d, int e) {
    // basically, here will just create a function (eg: addUser/User registration)
}
```

Pro1 code example:

```
public class Pro1 {
    ...
    public Response method1() {
        // intialize the variables

        //call the method in Pro2
        Pro2 pro2 = new Pro2();
        int storeMethod1 = pro2.method1(a, b, c, d, e);

        //return the storeMethod1 if able to call method1
        if (storeMethod1 == pro2.toString(method1)) {
             returnData.put("message" , "Success");
        } else {
             returnData.put("message", "Invalid Input");
        }

        return Response.ok (gson.toJson(returnData), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Project 2" to your "Project 1" Libraries.

To do this in netbeans:

1. Right click on project 1
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select "Libraries"
4. Select "Compile"
5. Select "Add Project"
6. Select Project 2
7. Click "Ok"

Comment: I've already add it to the libraries. There's no error in that. At first I tried with this: if (storeMethod1 == pro2.method1()) but got error "cannot be applied to given types;". And also this if (storeMethod1 .equals(pro2.method1())) but I got error "int cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: @umika1150 and if you move this method into the same class as pro1 it works fine?

Comment: no. there's still error in the if statement. I always got "int cannot be dereferenced". When I change the code following what I founf in google how to resolve those types of problem , I got error. It's so confusing.

Comment: @umika1150 is the code in the question the most recent?

Comment: @umika1150 it looks like you are comparing a `int` to a String.

Comment: yes it seems like it. I have omitted that part because it seems like a redundant process. Thank you for your help.